# C# SQL DELETE RETURN ONLY TRUE

Tags: c#

My code its return only true and I don't know where it is.

```
public bool Delete(int RGP)
{
    vsql = "DELETE FROM pescador WHERE RGP LIKE @RGP";
    SqlCommand cmd = null;

    if (this.Conectar())
    {
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RGP", RGP);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return true;
        }
        catch(SqlException sqlerro)
        {
            throw sqlerro;
        }

        finally
        {
            this.Desconectar();
        }
    }
    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: It's good that its returning `true` that means your SQL command worked!

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your problem? What do you mean by _don't know where it is_? Have you _ever_ debug your code and see what is going on? If it always returns `true`, that means your `this.Conectar()` is always `true`.

Comment: my code is always returning true and never false wonder why

Comment: This is not a WONDER!! It is returning true because you have put `return true;` in your code!!

Comment: Look at the code. You have `return true` hardcoded in the `Try` block. What else would you expect it to return? In fact, how does this even compile? There is no return path in the `catch` or `finally` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

Look: this fragment is useless:

```
  catch(SqlException sqlerro)
  {
    throw sqlerro; // exception catched and thrown unmodified
  }
```

If you want to return false when *query fails*:

```
  catch(SqlException sqlerro) {
    return false;
  }
```

In case you want to return false if *no records are changed*:

```
  return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
```

Finally, do not forget *using*, *arrowhead antipattern*, *readability* etc.

```
public bool Delete(int RGP) {
  // Argument/State validation
  if (objCon == null)
    return false; // No connection

  // SQL should be readable
  vsql = @"delete 
             from Pescador 
            where Rgp like @RGP";

  try {
    // Dispose IDisposable (via using)
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon)) {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RGP", RGP);
      //TODO: be sure that SET NOCOUNT is not ON 
      return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
    }
  }
  finally {
    Desconectar();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are always returning true. check you code. this should be like this :

```
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
return Convert.ToBoolean(i);
```

Or :

```
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(i > 0)
    i = 1;
else
    i = 0;
return Convert.ToBoolean(i);
```

Comment: `return cmd.ExecuteQuery() > 0;` i.e. number of *changed records* are more than zero

Comment: `Convert.ToBoolean(int)` only returns false if the argument == 0. `ExecuteNonQuery` can return -1, which would return true, which is probably not what OP wants.

Comment: Why this would help to OP _anyway_? The question is not even clear at all.